# Does the Sun have different unique orbits around barycenters?

Tags: the-sun, orbit, planet, solar-system

After reading [this](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/44583/why-doesnt-the-sun-wobble-towards-jupiter-instead-of-away-from-jupiter) question and seeing its image I thought about this question I'm going to publish.

Does the Sun have different unique orbits around the barycenter for its multiple planets?

If yes, how does it revolve around all of them? For this it has to exit one orbit and enter another.

Comment: There is just one barycenter - the center of mass of all combined bodies. There isn't a unique barycenter for the Sun-Mercury system, Sun-Venus system, etc.

Comment: Those barycenters have exactly as much reality as the solar system barycenter has. They're _all_ just calculated relative positions based on the positions and masses of the objects you choose to include in the calculation.

Comment: Related question: https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/44851/is-the-barycenter-of-the-solar-system-usually-outside-of-the-sun

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's only one barycenter for the solar system, which includes the impact from every planet, asteroid, comet, and space probe in the solar system.  The path the sun takes around that barycenter is *mostly* a circle because the Sun-Jupiter interaction completely dominates the physics of the system, but it's a bit wobbly due to all the interacting forces of the other bodies (mostly Saturn).

You can calculate the location of the barycenter between the sun and any other body in the system, but the sun doesn't continually switch which one of those it's paying attention to. It has to obey all of them all the time, leading to a complicated wobbly path around the single Solar System barycenter.

But it doesn't stop there, because all those other bodies are pulling on each other as well -- even as Jupiter is pulling on the sun and Saturn is pulling on the sun, those two are pulling on each other, making their orbits wobble as well, which feeds back into the sun's wobble. It's an almost infinitely complex interaction of forces.

Comment: FWIW, the speed of the Sun relative to the SSB is quite slow, with a mean ~12.67 m/s, see the graph at the end of https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/a/28036/16685